# Navigate with ionic angular

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, navigation

I'm new to using ionic, but and I've been trying to navigate through pages, lets say I want to go from a signin page, to the tabs page. As of now I don't want to implement any backend API, I just need the login button to link itself to the next page. [Currently this is how I've implemented it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vvk4s.png). I have a path for /tabs in my app routing module, however when clicking this button nothing happens.

Comment: Hi trynalearn! Please share your code in text, not in an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer of @Everton Costa is part of the answer but will do a bit edit in it.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule)
  }
];
```

And in order to perform the navigation, either on the button itself u put attribute routerLink like

```
<ion-button routerLink="/home"></ion-button>
```

or we could access it from code like add in login.component.ts file the following :

first u add at the top of this page this line:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

and in the constructor u add this:

```
constructor(private router: Router){}

navigateToPage(route: string) {
    this.router.navigate([route]);
}
```

and in html :

```
<ion-button (click)="navigateToPage('/home')"></ion-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is important to care about your routes file `app-routing.module.ts` to see how it is implemented. Follows a suggestion:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/tabs-page/tabs-page.module').then(m => m.TabsModule)
  }
];
```